# How do I change my starting block?

Tags: kirbys-dream-buffet

I noticed other players have different starting blocks in Kirby's Dream Buffet. How do I change my starting block?

[image: starting blocks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting block is determined by the decoration on top of your cake. Roll over to the Character Treats Collection to change it.

[image: changing the cake topper]